# How can I delete duplicate mysql column entries?

Tags: mysql

I have a mysql table named "dev" with a column of "email"s.  I want to select out all the unique e-mail addresses and delete the duplicates.

My structure is as follows:

```
id    ||    email
1           user1@example.com
2           userB@example.com
3           user1@example.com
```

What I want is...

```
id    ||    email
1           user1@example.com
2           userB@example.com
```

What mysql query can I used to accomplish this?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a new table and select the elements you want to keep into the new table. If you don't need to retain the original ids then you can do this:

```
INSERT INTO dev2 (email)
SELECT DISTINCT(email)
FROM dev
```

If you need to retain the id of the first row for each the email address then use this instead:

```
INSERT INTO dev2 (id, email)
SELECT MIN(id), email
FROM dev
GROUP BY email
```

Once you have filled the new table you can drop the original table then rename the new table to the correct name.